# Pass 2D array from this.setState() in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays

Let's say i have this 2d array :

```
let cart =[
["Corn", "Potato", "Radish"],
["Tomato", "Graphes", "Mango"],
];
```

which is diaplayed inside JSX like this:

```
<div>
  {cart.map((items, index) => {
    return (
      <ol>
        {items.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
          return <li> {subItems} </li>;
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

But in my project, the 2D array named "r" is inside setState():

```
getResult(value) {

    let r = value;

    this.setState({
        resultToJSX: r
    });
}
```

How can i pass it to JSX from this.setState ?

Thanks for the support here !

Answer (score 0):

All your state properties in the this.state object.

```
this.state.resultToJSX
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it already, and got this error:                                                                    Uncaught TypeError: this.state.resultToJSX.map is not a function

Comment: Maybe it is undefined on initial page load, use this.state.resultToJSX?.map

Comment: Just add? like this : this.state.resultToJSX?.map   ?, that didn't helped, Thanks for responding though

Comment: Would you mind providing a full example of your code?

Comment: Maybe you can use sandbox to recreate the issue live, so we can help you.

Comment: This is a Sandbox repo for react.
https://codesandbox.io/s/new